# Proper way to check for empty/no query result

Tags: php, pdo

I am using a standard PDO connection to connect to a mysql database (using the attribute PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) for my user login system.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid= ? OR useremail = ?;";
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$userid, $useremail]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($result == null) {
    header("Location: login.php?error=usernotfound");
    die();
}
```

`if ($result == null)` is the solution I've currently implemented. I've seen similar ways to check for no results like `$row < 1`, `empty($result)`, `count($result) < 1` etc. Is there a "best" and most secure solution for this considering results like empty strings, null, undefined ...?

Comment: [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) will never return `null` so a better check would be `if (empty($result))` since it would cover both a valid query with no matches (empty array) and an invalid query (false).